# Wifi Driver and additional drivers issue with Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04, kernel

A few days ago I updated my UBUNTU 16.04 version with 18.04.1

But after that, my wifi stopped working on my laptop.
I'm using Acer E515 laptop and my wireless card manufacturer is Qualcomm.

I also tried with lots of solution links on stack-overflow, askubuntu, and other youtube videos but nothing is working for me.

Lots of videos and links are saying go to your 'Software Update' and click on 'Additional Drivers' Tab and proceed.

But in my case 'Additional Drivers' tab is showing 'No additional drivers available'.

Yesterday, I was tried with this link:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392454

But on the last step, it's giving an error (this package is deleted something like this) related to 'linux-header-kernel' 4.0.3-generic something.

when i run 'uname -r' command
then it's showing :- 'linux-header-kernel-4.0.3-generic' something.(I don't know what was actually)

Please help me guys,
I can't make a full-day Ethernet or Cable connection to my laptop.

Thanks

Comment: It is not useful to attempt to install Realtek drivers for your Atheros card. Please provide full diagnostics from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: What should i share with you? @chili555

Comment: # kernel #
Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
# lspci #
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
 Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:08a6]
 Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
03:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
 Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:1094]
 Kernel driver in use: r8169

Comment: Please download the script in the link I provided, run it and paste the result: http://paste.ubuntu.com and give us the link.

Comment: Please check @chili555
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/C6Sc6P4d3p/

Comment: How is it that you are running kernel version 4.4-xx and Ubuntu 18.04? The usual kernel for 18.04 is 4.15-xx. Have you updated since installation? What does this tell us? `ls /boot`

Comment: Before 3 days ago, I updated it 16.04 to 18.04

Comment: How can I fix it without losing my data, please help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84061/discussion-between-chili555-and-rk-verma).